# *（アスタリスク）を出力するC言語プログラムを作成したい

Tags: c

整数配列dataに対し、その要素の数だけ*を表示するプログラムを作成したのですが、うまく行きません。

以前にも、整数配列dataに対して、その数を表示するプログラムは作成したことがあるのですが、その応用だと思って、最初は以下のようにプログラムを作成しました。

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
      printf("%d番目? ",i+1);
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
}
void printIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
      printf("%d ",a[i]); 
}
printf("\n");
}

void put_AstArray(int a[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("* ");
      printIntArray(i);
    }printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[100], size;
    
    printf("n=? ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    readIntArray(data, size);
    printIntArray(data, size);
    put_AstArray(data,size);
    return 0;
}
```

しかし、作成してみたものの、エラーが出てしまいます。
どうしたら、以下のような期待している結果が出力されるのでしょうか。
**＜期待しているコンパイル結果＞**

```
$ ./a.out
n=? 4
1番目? 1
2番目? 3
3番目? 4
4番目? 2
a[1]:*
a[2]:***
a[3]:****
a[4]:**
```

Comment: gccがエラーのところと原因を出力するはずですが。。。

Comment: gccがあれば答がわかるのでしょうか。また、gccはコンパイル時に実行できるものなのか、それとも新たにインストールする必要があるものなのかを教えてほしいです。

Comment: 今どのツール、またどのシステムを使っていますか。そのプロンプト`$`を見て、linux系のシステムを使っていると思ったのです。それだと、普通gccがインストール済みと思います。

Comment: もしほかのコンパイラを使ったら、エラーが出ても、log出力が全くないですか。

Comment: 普段どのようにして実行していますか？ソースファイルを保存してからa.outを実行する間に何らかの操作をしていると思うのですが

Comment: ソースファイルを保存してから（そのソースファイル内にはもうすでにプログラムされている状態で）、cc ソースファイル名.cとコンパイルを実行しています。

Comment: ccは標準のコンパイラを呼び出すもので、実際の中身はgccだったりclangだったりします。 `man cc` と入力してみてください。なんかだらだらと出てくると思いますが、NAMEの部分を確認してください。終了するにはQを押します

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gccが以下のエラーを出力しました：

> main.c:25: error: too few arguments to function 'printIntArray'

25行目を見ると、`printIntArray(i);`の入力引数が一つで、関数定義`void printIntArray(int a[], int size)`と不一致です。

【変更を始めます】

`main`に関数の呼び出しが期待している出力と違いです。　　
「`X番目? X`」の行は`readIntArray`関数で、「`a[X]:X`」の行は`put_AstArray`関数で出力したんです。`printIntArray`関数は`data`アレイに保存する各入力数字しかを出力しないです。ここに必要ない。

```
    readIntArray(data, size);
//    printIntArray(data, size);  // <--- 必要ない
    put_AstArray(data,size);
```

`put_AstArray`関数に`for`ループをまた一つ追加します。　　
`i`変数のループ範囲は`main`関数の最初に入力した`n`の値です。　　
`j`変数のループ範囲は`X番目`に入力した`*`の数です。期待している数の`*`を出力ためです。

```
void put_AstArray(int a[],int size)
{
/////////////////////////
//    int i;
//    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
//      printf("* ");
//      printIntArray(i);
//    }printf("\n");
/////////////////////////   ↓へ変更
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("a[%d]:",i+1);
      for(j=0;j<a[i];j++){
        printf("*");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。修正するとともに説明を添えてくれたので、とても見やすく参考になりました。